# What does "Origin" mean in NCBI GenBank?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, ncbi

I'm having trouble determining what exactly is meant by the term "Origin" in this case. It is just before a 70 bp sequence that the page claims is a plasmid, but does not specify it to be what I assume is incomplete, seeing as I don't think there is such a thing as a 70 bp plasmid (correct me if I'm wrong). So do they mean the origin of replication to the plasmid?

Here is the page in question: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/M30888.1?report=genbank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The ORIGIN may be left blank, may appear as "Unreported," or may give a local pointer to the sequence start, usually involving an experimentally determined restriction cleavage site or the genetic locus (if available). This information is present only in older records.
>
> The sequence data begin on the line immediately below ORIGIN.

[[source]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Sitemap/samplerecord.html#OriginB)

Given that it's left blank in your file, it doesn't signify anything other than the end of the annotation and beginning of the raw sequence.